# Laravel 5.3 : Array Push Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want parse data with json in laravel 5.3 but i got message

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$bulan

```
   public function chart()
    {
      $bulan = [];
      $jumlah = [];
      $data[] = DB::table('data_peminjaman')
                    ->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y') as tahun ,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') as bulan,COUNT(*) as jumlahdata, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as b"))
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M'),DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m')"))
                    ->orderBy('tahun')
                    ->orderBy('b')
                    ->get();
      foreach ($data as $key ) {
        array_push($bulan, $key->bulan);
        array_push($jumlah, $key->jumlahdata);
      }
      // return view('chart',$data);
      return view('chart', compact('bulan', 'jumlah'));
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean "I can't push" ? What is "Array Push error"? Please be more specific what the problem is.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek i got message 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$bulan'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$data[] = DB::table('data_peminjaman')
                    ->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y') as tahun ,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') as bulan,COUNT(*) as jumlahdata, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as b"))
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M'),DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m')"))
                    ->orderBy('tahun')
                    ->orderBy('b')
                    ->get();
```

you should use:

```
$data = DB::table('data_peminjaman')
                    ->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y') as tahun ,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M') as bulan,COUNT(*) as jumlahdata, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as b"))
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M'),DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m')"))
                    ->orderBy('tahun')
                    ->orderBy('b')
                    ->get();
```

The only difference here is `$data[]` vs `$data`.

Also instead of:

```
foreach ($data as $key ) {
    array_push($bulan, $key->bulan);
    array_push($jumlah, $key->jumlahdata);
}
```

you can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
$bulan = $data->pluck('bulan');
$jumlah = $data->pluck('jumlahdata');
```